# Deny access to unauthenticated users with django channels

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I'm basically after a `login_required`/`LoginRequiredMixin` equivalent for django channels. The docs have an [authentication section](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started.html#authentication), which describes how to get a user, but it seems to miss the bit where you actually deny access to users who are not authenticated.

```
from channels.generic.websockets import JsonWebsocketConsumer

class MyConsumer(JsonWebsocketConsumer):

    channel_session_user = True

    def connection_groups(self, **kwargs):
        return ["test"]

    def connect(self, message, **kwargs):
        print message.user # AnonymousUser
        self.send({"accept": True}) # False here still accepts and sends a message
```

How should I be denying/dropping the connection if `message.user.is_anonymous` is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denying the connection on connect attempt is as simple as this: do not send the accept message at all if you don't want to establish a connection. Channels will close it automatically after a configured amount of time (5 seconds or smth like that by default).

```
def connect(self, message, **kwargs):
    if not message.user.is_anonymous:
        self.send({"accept": True})
```

If you do not want to wait and close the connection immediately, just send `{"close": True}` instead:

```
def connect(self, message, **kwargs):
    if not message.user.is_anonymous:
        self.send({"accept": True})
    else:
        self.send({"close": True})
```

For the sake of completeness, here is the explanation from the [channels docs](http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releases/1.0.0.html#connect-consumers). Sadly, this information is not listed in the documentation itself, only in release notes to v1.0.

Comment: Can a channel be closed or is it necessary to wait for the timeout?

Comment: @jozxyqk: sure, if you want to explicitly close the connection and do not want to wait for `channels` to close it, send `{"close": True}` instead of `{"accept": True}`. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
if user.is_authenticated():
    # allow it
```

Comment: Just to clarify, `AnonymousUser.is_authenticated` will always return false? My question was also asking how to disallow it.